# Applying physics to multiple objects at the same time

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm triyng to apply smoke flow to multiple objects at the same time (in the same domain, with blender internal).
I Know it's possible for Rigod bodies, with the *'copy from active'* button, but I can't find how for smoke...

The leads I've followed, without success:

- copying physics properties from an object to others (not successful)
- selecting multiple object at the same time and applying smoke domain in the phycis tab (idem)
- the best I've managed to do: I've noticed that it's possible to apply smoke to multiple objects at the same time by selecting all the desired objects, and applying a "quick smoke". But I don't know how to adjust the default "quick smoke" properties of the flow objects...

So I've tried to look at the `object_quick_effects.py`, to modify the default properties, but nothing seems to refer at the flow domain...

I assume it should be possible with scripting, but I don't know anything about python, and I was wondering if there was a simpler way?

---

#### Edit

I've finally resolved this problem: As soon as the smoke flow is a modifier, we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to copy the modifier on one mesh to all the other selected ones.